# how can i get variable in a function?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

i am developing a plugin in which i search for a particular method.Now i want to display all the variable declared and used in it along with their types.How can i do that?method name is of IMethod type.Help

Comment: Let's be clear: Are you asking about Java, or about Eclipse's `IMethod` interface? http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/eclipse/jdt/doc/isv/3.2.1-r321_v20060907/isv-3.2.1-r321_v20060907.jar!/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/IMethod.html

Comment: Eclipse's IMethod type.sorry my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the CompilationUnit of that IMethod, you could use a [**`ASTParser`**](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTParser.java.htm) as [illustrated here](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.jdt/msg17244.html)):

```
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
parser.setSource(compilationUnit);
parser.setSourceRange(method.getSourceRange().getOffset(), method.getSourceRange().getLength());
parser.setResolveBindings(true);
CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit)parser.createAST(null);
cu.accept(new ASTMethodVisitor());
```

Then you can use an **[`ASTVisitor`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTVisitor.java.htm)**

```
cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
  public boolean visit(SimpleName node) {
    System.out.println(node); // print all simple names in compilation unit. in our example it would be A, i, j (class name, and then variables)
    // filter the variables here
    return true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the Java reflection API. Have a look at this: [link text](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html)

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure he's talking about the `IMethod` interface of Eclipse: http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/eclipse/jdt/doc/isv/3.2.1-r321_v20060907/isv-3.2.1-r321_v20060907.jar!/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/IMethod.html And regardless, reflection doesn't tell you about variables declared inside a method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to get the types of all the parameters required by the method.

First reflect the method using Class, then use `Method.getParameterTypes()'.